# Change Twentyeleven Search Form Text

Tags: search, theme-twenty-eleven

Anyone know how to change the text inside the Twentyeleven search field from "Search" to another choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `searchform.php` Find this in line 12 and edit Search as you wish

```
placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"
```